# BAD REQUEST with passport.authenticate()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I'm a little new to using passportjs in authenticating users and i'm trying to register a user on a simple application i'm building and i keep getting this error "Bad Request" in the browser. The user does get created in the DB but the redirect doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this question has been asked before :)

I have attached some bits of my code.

```
User.register(new User({username : req.body.user_email}), req.body.user_password, function(err, user){
    if(err) {
        return res.render("register-user", { userDetails : user})
    }

    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/profile");
    })
})
```

My user Schema is as follows:

```
const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i did a little more digging and i found the answer to my problem. It seems to be that passportjs requires the form inputs to have username and password as their name attributes before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, the user object argument was not complete, you didn't include the password path, check the fixed code below:

```
User.register(new User({
    username : req.body.user_email,
    password: req.body.user_password}), 
    function(err, user){
    if(err) {
     return res.render("register-user", { userDetails : user})
    }
  passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
    res.redirect("/profile");
   })
   })
```

Comment: Hi @Isiaka, I tried what you suggested and got this error "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "password" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type function ([Function])"

Comment: hi @Isiaka, So i did a little more digging and i found the answer to my problem. It seems to be that passportjs requires the form inputs to have username and password as their name attributes before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution to this problem is making the form inputs have exactly username and password as the name attribute. The new user should also have this format

```
<input type="email" name="username">

<input type="password" name="password">
```

and in your js file

```
    const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
})
```

Comment: yup, that's it.